# Fade in and out bug with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page, when the user gets to say 1000 pixels scrolled down the page, my navigation fades out, when i scroll back up the navigation fades in. Im using the following which works perfectly...

```
// Fade Navigation

if(!$('nav ul').is(':visible')) {
    $('nav ul').stop().fadeIn(500);
} else {
    $('nav ul').stop().fadeOut(500);
}
```

My only problem is that if you scroll really quickly, the animation doesnt know if its visible or not, is there a way to stop this?

Comment: What browser? Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us?

Comment: I don't think `:visible` works that way --- even if elements are scrolled out of view, they are considered `:visible` if they are still taking up space in the document. Also, you might be happy to know that there is a `.fadeToggle()` function!

Comment: jQuery knows exactly whether your element is visible or not. Thing is, `.stop()`ing a `fadeOut` animation leaves the element partially visible which is considered `:visible`.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in `true` as a second parameter to `.stop()`, it'll stop the animation *and* jump the element to the state it should be in if the animation actually finished.

i.e. if you call `$('nav ul').stop(true, true).fadeIn(500)` while an element is fading out, it will stop the fade out, *and* make it jump to it's logical end (which is completely faded out) *before* starting the `.fadeIn()` animation.

Using that, you should be able to get away with the following instead of your code block above:

```
$('nav ul').stop(true, true).fadeToggle(500);
```

It'll look a little jerky though, but you can work around it with a bit more complicated logic.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with this.  See comments in code.

```
<nav class="main">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Do this outside of the onscroll handler.  onscroll is fired a lot,
    // so performance will slow if you're having to create jq instances
    // or navigate the dom several times
    var $wnd = $(window);
    var $nav = $('nav.main');

    // Added this to block the main handler from executing
    // while we are fading in or out...in attempt
    // to smooth the animation
    var blockHandler = false;

    window.onscroll = function () {
        if (!blockHandler) {
            blockHandler = true;

            // I've used 50 here, but calc the offset of your nav
            // and add the height to it.  Or, maybe just half the
            // height to it so you can see the animation.
            if ($wnd.scrollTop() < 50) {
                $nav.fadeIn(500, function () {
                    blockHandler = false;
                });
            } else {
                $nav.fadeOut(500, function () {
                    blockHandler = false;
                });
            }
        }
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry mate, didn't mean to offend you, but I thought Liam was having trouble getting his menu to fade in and out smoothly, hence why I've posted something "I've been playing around with", which may well give him new ideas on how to achieve what he wants.

Comment: Generally, answers have an explanation to accompany the code, especially when so much of it appears to be irrelevant.  It's jQuery, no need to test for browsers... that's the point of using it.

Comment: This time my explanation was in the form of comments in the code.  The getScrollOffsets function is something I have in a lib so I copied it.  I've edited the code and used $.scrollTop instead.